# Sumifs or index match?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

Thank you for helping me out. I am working on a way to add up how many pieces each department is handling per week...My data are organized as below. Each row represents an order. There is an order qty. And the orange grid has the week numbers during which the department is handling that order.

Data layout

[image]

I am trying to summarize by week how many pieces each department is handling..and While I have a series of sumif statements to work around, I am wondering if the brain trust has a more elegant solution...Thanks again.

desired output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show your expected result?

Comment: @Harun24HR Thank you for your response. I am including the result I am after. For now I am using a series of sumif statements...

Comment: Give a try of my answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MMULT()` with `SUMPRODUCT()` may give you expected result.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(($C$2:$G$4=$A8)*($C$1:$G$1=B$7),TRANSPOSE({1,1,1,1,1}))*($B$2:$B$4))
```

You may need to enter the formula as array entry means confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If you have <kbd>Excel O365</kbd> then you can use dynamic formula `SEQUENCE()` which will give you best performance for large numbers of columns. Try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(($C$2:$G$4=$A8)*($C$1:$G$1=B$7),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($C$1:$G$1),,,0))*($B$2:$B$4))
```

[image]

Comment: Woooooah, both formulae worked, thank you so much. Thank you for teaching me the use of these functions.

Comment: Glad to know! Then please accept the answer (tick mark it) to mark the thread as solved.

Comment: I broke down the formula function by function to see just its output, this is brilliant, I thought my knowledge of excel was pretty good....until your formula...There is so much more for me to learn.